# What style screw terminal is this?

Tags: sensor, pcb-design

we have found a design of screw terminal that we really like but we are having lots of problems trying to source this specific part, I was hoping somebody here may recognize the design and know where to find the part. I have attached some images of the terminal opened and closed. With a typical screw terminal the screw clamps down onto a wire securing it, in this style the screw pulls up a nut that clamps the wire. I hope the pictures are clear and show what I'm describing.

[tb1 http://www.rtdcontrols.com/images/TB1.jpg](http://www.rtdcontrols.com/images/TB1.jpg)
Terminal block closed:
[tb1 http://www.rtdcontrols.com/images/TB2.jpg](http://www.rtdcontrols.com/images/TB2.jpg)
Terminal block open:
[tb1 http://www.rtdcontrols.com/images/TB3.jpg](http://www.rtdcontrols.com/images/TB3.jpg)

Any info about this would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Are there no markings, logos, part numbers, etc. anywhere on the part or moulding?

Comment: I know what the device is as a whole, I'm looking to recreate that style of screw terminal. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: The photos are quite blurry. Hurts to look at them. Try using the Macro Mode of a camera or something, or take a picture further out and crop it down.

Answer (score 1):

As David Tweed says, it appears this is not what the OP has in the photo. I'll leave the answer in case its useful for someone doing a similar thing.

It's called a "captive-clamp screw".

The terminal block itself is probably custom on that product, which looks like an head-mounted industrial process control transmitter.

[image: http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70088665]

Comment: Yes you are correct it is a transmitter, the screw is similar to that captive screw, however in this design the screw threads into the nut and moves freely through the brass colored part, and the black plastic is what keeps the screw from falling out. I have done a lot of research and I too think it must be a custom part, however I don't know where to get something like that made for a reasonable price.

Comment: The clamp rises with the screw head because it is captive. The captive screw is done via the custom molding. Moldings are very reasonable in cost if purchased in sufficient volume, (but not in small quantities because the mold itself is expensive, and high quality molds can easily run tens of thousands of dollars). If you have small quantities you could try 3D printing the plastic, but the appearance and performance cannot compare with a well-made injection molded part.

Comment: You've misinterpreted the OP's picture. There, the clamping nut is the *bottom-most* piece, and rises to clamp against the brass piece in the middle when the screw is tightened. The screw head turns, but does not move up or down at all. In other words, it's just an ordinary screw and an ordinary square nut, and the brass piece in the middle (which is the fixed electrical contact) simply has a clearance hole for the screw (i.e., it is not threaded).

Comment: @DaveTweed Looks like that's correct.